# replace or operate within regex match

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, global-command

**underlying question:** Is there a way to operate on text within a regex match?
I.e. is there an analog to the 'g' command that operates on match substrings instead of lines

**usecases:**
One example of this would be if you replace a pattern within a pattern without a huge amount of regex gymnastics (which are often possible with much effort). A specific example might be replace spaces with tabs but only in text matching a regex.

```
field1 field2 field3 field4 field with spaces
```

Another specific example would be if you wanted to replace - with _ but only in text inside quotes

```
You should name your file [something something something]
and name their file [a b c d]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe your solution is to use a sub-replace-expression ([`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression))

For example in your first example let's say that I want to replace spaces with underscores (because it's more visual in this answer) but only in the last field `field with spaces`:

```
field1 field2 field3 field4 field with spaces
```

I could use this command:

```
:s/field w.*/\=substitute(submatch(0), '_', ' ', 'g')/

 s/                                                     Substitution command
   field w.*                                            Make the substitution only on the part of the string you want to match
            /
             \=                                         Replace with an expression
               substitute(           , ' ', '_', 'g')   Use the substitution() function to replace spaces with underscore
                          submatch(0)                   Give the matched string as parameter of substitute()
```

This will result in

```
field1 field2 field3 field4 field_with_spaces
```

This idea is to use the `substitute()` function inside the replacement part of the `:s` command. `submatch(0)` is a reference to the pattern matched by `:s`.

In the same idea to replace `something something something` by `something_something_something` in your second example you could do this:

```
:s/\[.*\]/\=substitute(submatch(0), ' ', '_', 'g')/
```

You might want to read the following help topics:

- [`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression)
- [`:h submatch()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#submatch%28%29)
- [`:h substitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29)

Comment: That looks super useful!  That seems to be pretty close to ideal. I'll just leave the question open for a short while longer in case there are any other interesting solutions.